# "Jetty is not installed" on boot, and poweroff

Tags: 12.10, boot

Every time I boot, or poweroff (without quiet and splash params) I get a red massage saying "Jetty is not installed".

What is Jetty, and why am I getting this?

Comment: It had been a while. Still looking for an answer?

Comment: No, I figured! Forgot how, though.

Answer (score -1):

This command "sudo apt-get purge jetty" to correct this error.

Comment: Sorry, my edit was premature. What's the intent of this? That *removes* Jetty, and its systemwide configuration files. Do you recommend *reinstalling* it as well? That could be achieved with `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install jetty`.